# Numpy dstack causing memory error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of shape:

```
x.shape # (50000, 784)
y.shape # (50000,)
```

However, when I use column_stack I get `MemoryError`

```
X_y = np.column_stack([X, y])
# ... MemoryError.
```

My desired outcome is to add y as another column to X

```
X_y.shape # (50000, 785)
```

I have also tried

```
X_y = list(zip(X, Y)) 
random.shuffle(X_y)
X, Y = zip(*X_y)
X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)
```

And it also causes `MemoryError` on the final line

The way in which I get to this error is as follows:

```
TrainX = np.loadtxt("TrainDigitX.csv.gz", delimiter=",")
TrainY = np.loadtxt("TrainDigitY.csv.gz", delimiter=",")

NN = Neural_Network((784, 30, 10))
mini_batch_size = 20
epochs = 30

for epoch in range(epochs):
    TrainX = TrainX.T.tolist()
    TrainX.append(TrainY)
    X_match_y = np.array(TrainX).T
    np.random.shuffle(X_match_y)
#... continue to run NN
```

Comment: This worked for me, and gave me your expected output.

Comment: @coldspeed Would it be my computer causing the `MemoryError` ? Or what other reason? I am using PyCharm IDE with Python 3.6

Comment: Try `X = X.T.tolist(); X.append(y); X_y = np.array(X).T`

Comment: Do you anything else in the workspace?  You shouldn't get a memory error unless memory is already so full that you can't even make a copy of `X`.

Comment: @coldspeed MemoryError at `X_y = np.array(X).T`

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but something is clearly wrong... numpy arrays work well even with millions of elements.

Comment: @coldspeed I read both numpy arrays from `X = np.loadtxt("TrainDigitX.csv.gz", delimiter=",")` would this cause anything?

Comment: I can't say for sure... we will need more info and/or context to diagnose the problem...

Comment: @coldspeed I have just updated the post with more information about how I get to the point that throws `MemroryError`